# Trying to get the CGColor value from a property causes crash

Tags: objective-c, properties, cgcolor

I'm trying to set a property like so -

-interface:

```
@property (readwrite, assign) CGColorRef otherBallColor;
```

-someMethod:

```
CGColorRef ballColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/256.0 green:165.0/256.0 blue:239.0/256.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;  
[self setOtherBallColor:ballColor];
```

As soon as I try to access the value it crashes -

-someOtherMethod (drawRect in this case):

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, otherBallColor);
```

But if in the "someMethod" I do -

```
CGColorRef ballColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
```

... it all works fine. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Many thanks (PS, quite new to Objective-C, tho not programming in general)

Comment: You should divide by 255 instead of 256.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must retain returned CGColor, your [UIColor colorWith...] creates an auto-released instance, so, when it is out of scope (autoreleased I mean), corresponding CGColor is released as well.

I'd recommend you to use UIColor instead of CGColorRef if i is possible in this case.

Comment: ... and use CGColorRetain instead of `-retain`.

Comment: Thanks - I've just tried versions of this, including :

UIColor *ballUIColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/256.0 green:165.0/256.0 blue:239.0/256.0 alpha:1.0] retain];
[self setOtherBallColor:ballUIColor.CGColor];
[ballUIColor release];

...& it still crashes when I access the value in drawRect. I'm a bit stumped... (also tried autorelease to no avail)

Comment: Yes, or (what I personally prefer) use higher level object where it is possible. UI/NS classes look better, read easier and they are easier to manage in most cases

Comment: CGColorRetain! Thanks - where do you find this stuff? I thought I was checking the documentation quite thoroughly, but I missed that. I did wonder though how I was supposed to retain something which wasn't an object like a UIColor...

Comment: Might also have something to do with this.  It was my issue and led me to a solution: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/06/radar-arc-releases-uicolor-prematurely/

Answer (score 1):

Talk about a late answer, but I've got an alternative solution to this particular problem, which I ran into a little while ago.  I found this question before the solution, so I figured I'd throw in my two cents.  It turns out that `UIColor` has an instance method called `setFill`, which sets the receiver as the current context fill color.  So you could write:

```
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[[UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:165.0/255.0 
                  blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] setFill];
CGContextFillPath(myContext);
```

I find this a cleaner solution, because you don't have to worry about retaining or subsequently releasing any `CGColor`s.  In fact, you don't even have to deal with any Core Graphics fill color setting commands, like `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor`.

You can check out the `- (void)setFill` method in more detail in the [UIColor Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006892-CH3-SW1).